# Angular.js Unit/Integration Testing - Trigger Link Function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently, I am writing a test (using Jasmine) for a directive, and I suspect the link function is not being triggered.

The directive is as follows:

```
.directive('userWrapperUsername', [
    'stringEntryGenerateTemplate',
    'stringEntryGenerateLinkFn',
    // UserWrapper username column
    // Attribute: 'user-wrapper-username'
    // Attribute argument: A UserWrapper object with a 'newData' key into an
    //                     object, which contains a 'username' key holding the
    //                     UserWrapper's username
    function(stringEntryGenerateTemplate, stringEntryGenerateLinkFn) {
        return {
            template: stringEntryGenerateTemplate('username'),
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            link: stringEntryGenerateLinkFn('userWrapperUsername', 'username')
        };
    }
])
```

So it makes use of 2 functions provided through factories, namely `stringEntryGenerateTemplate` and `stringEntryGenerateLinkFn`.

The `stringEntryGenerateTemplate` function takes in a string and returns a string.

The `stringEntryGenerateLinkFn` function, when called returns the actual link function. It mostly consists of event handlers so I shall simplify it to:

```
function stringEntryGenerateLinkFn(directiveName, key) {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.state = {};
        scope.userWrapper = scope.$eval(attr[directiveName]);
    }
}
```

Here is how I use the directive:

```
<div user-wrapper-username="u"></div>
```

Here is my test case:

```
describe('UserWrapper Table string entry', function() {
    var $scope
      , $compile;
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$compile_) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $compile = _$compile_;
    }));
    it('should be in stateDisplay if the value is non empty', function() {
        var userWrapper = {
                orgData: {
                    student: {
                        hasKey: true,
                        value: 'abcdef'
                    }
                },
                newData: {
                    student: {
                        hasKey: true,
                        value: 'abcdef',
                        changed: false
                    }
                }
            }
          , key = 'student'
          , elem
          , elemScope;
        $scope.userWrapper = userWrapper;
        elem = $compile('<div user-wrapper-username="userWrapper"></div>')($scope);
        elemScope = elem.scope();
        expect(elemScope.userWrapper).toBe(userWrapper);
        expect(elemScope.state).toEqual(jasmine.any(Object)); // this fails
    });
});
```

So I get a test failure saying that `elemScope.state` is undefined. Recall that I had a `scope.state = {};` statement and it should be executed if the link function is executed. I tried a `console.log` inside the link function and it is not executed as well.

So how do I trigger the link function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I have to initialize the module containing the factories `stringEntryGenerateTemplate` and `stringEntryGenerateLinkFn`, which is the same module that contains the `userWrapperUsername` directive by adding this into my test case:

```
beforeEach(module('userWrapper', function() {}));
```

where `userWrapper` is the name of the module.

So the test case becomes:

```
describe('UserWrapper Table string entry', function() {
    var $scope
      , $compile;
    beforeEach(module('userWrapper', function() {}));
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$compile_) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $compile = _$compile_;
    }));
    it('should be in stateDisplay if the value is non empty', function() {
        var userWrapper = {
                orgData: {
                    student: {
                        hasKey: true,
                        value: 'abcdef'
                    }
                },
                newData: {
                    student: {
                        hasKey: true,
                        value: 'abcdef',
                        changed: false
                    }
                }
            }
          , key = 'student'
          , elem
          , elemScope;
        $scope.userWrapper = userWrapper;
        elem = $compile('<div user-wrapper-username="userWrapper"></div>')($scope);
        elemScope = elem.scope();
        expect(elemScope.userWrapper).toBe(userWrapper);
        expect(elemScope.state).toEqual(jasmine.any(Object)); // this fails
    });
});
```

This seems like quite a big oversight on my part. Hopefully this will help anyone facing a similar issue.